# Fetch a complete git branch from another local repository

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a remote repository and 2 local repositories let say repo1 and repo2. I am working on a branch (project1) which is checked out from repo1. There is another branch (project2) which is checked out from repo2. Project2 branch  has my changes which I have committed but not pushed (Don't want to push). I want to fetch all changes from project2 to project1 branch. I did

```
git fetch <my repo2> project2
```

and then cherry-pick the latest commit. But It only fetch the latest commit changes. I tried to fetch between first and last commit but in this case it only fetch the first commit.

```
git fetch <my repo2> project2 && git cherry-pick <First commit SHA1>..<last Commit SHA1>
```

Could anyone please help me to find the problem. How can I fetch a complete branch from repo2 to repo1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to merge then merge:

```
git fetch <my repo2> project2 && git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

cherry-pick picks only single commit changes.

Comment: How can I see which files are merged in my branch?

git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <SHA1> shows nothing.

Comment: @zeeshan Try to use something like `git log --stat HEAD^1..FETCH_HEAD`. It means to show all commits with brief information about files in each commit. The commit range is between first parent of the merge commit (HEAD^1, i.e. your HEAD right before the merge) and the merged FETCH_HEAD.

Comment: Or just `git diff --name-only HEAD^1..FETCH_HEAD`